# Flask Error: ImportError cannot import name 'app' from 'app'

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I just started learning Flask and I'm building my first application.
The idea is to make an simple app where I can store in SQLite Students, Classes and Teachers.

To deliver this, I did just two python files:
app.py -> Creates the application and define routes
models.py -> Creates the db models in order to store them

Somehow, when I try to import app to models I get this error:

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/thiago/coding/eu-decidi/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/Users/thiago/coding/eu-decidi/app.py", line 6, in <module>
    from models import Student, Teacher, Meeting, stud_identifier
  File "/Users/thiago/coding/eu-decidi/models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import app
ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from 'app' (/Users/thiago/coding/eu-decidi/app.py)
```

Just gonna put here the code:

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, redirect, flash
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
from models import Student, Teacher, Meeting, stud_identifier

app = Flask(__name__) #application instance
app.config['SECRET_KEY']= 'my_secret'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///myDB.db' #path to database and its name
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False #supress warning of changes on database
db = SQLAlchemy(app) #database instance

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/students')
def students():
    return "Here are all our students"

@app.route('/teachers')
def teachers():
    return "Here are all our teachers"

@app.route('/classes')
def classes():
    return "Here are all our classes"

# app name 
@app.errorhandler(404) 
def not_found(e): 
  return "Page not found"
```

models.py:

```
from app import app
from app import db

stud_identifier = db.Table('stud_ident',
    db.Column('student', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('student.student_id')),
    db.Column('meeting', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('meeting.meeting_id'))
    )

class Student(db.Model):
    #__tablename__ = 'student'
    student_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True) #primary Key column, automatically generated IDs
    student_name = db.Column(db.String(80), index = True, unique = False) #name of student
    student_surname = db.Column(db.String(100), index = True, unique = False) #surname of student
    student_phone = db.Column(db.Integer, index=True, unique = True) #student phone number
    student_email = db.Column(db.String(200), index=True, unique = True) #student email
    #RELATIONSHIPS
    meetings = db.relationship('Meeting', secondary=stud_identifier, backref=db.backref('students', lazy='dynamic'))
 
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Aluno: {} {}, telefone: {}".format(self.student_name,self.student_surname,self.student_phone)

class Meeting(db.Model):
    #__tablename__='meeting'
    meeting_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key =True)
    meeting_date = db.Column(db.Date, index = True, unique=False) #date of the meeting
    meeting_subject = db.Column(db.String(80), index = True, unique=False) #subject of the meeting (Aula 1, Aula 2, Aula 3)
    #RELATIONSHIPS
    teacher_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('teacher.teacher_id'))
    #meeting.students.append(student) -> vai somar um aluno na tabela de identificação
    

class Teacher(db.Model):
    #__tablename__='teacher'
    teacher_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key =True)
    teacher_name = db.Column(db.String(80), index = True, unique = False) #name of Teacher
    teacher_surname = db.Column(db.String(100), index = True, unique = False) #surname of teacher
    teacher_phone = db.Column(db.Integer, index=True, unique = True) #teacher phone number
    teacher_email = db.Column(db.String(200), index=True, unique = True) #Teacher email
    #RELATIONSHIPS
    meetings = db.relationship('Meeting', uselist=False, backref='teacher')
```

Here is the repository as well:
[Repository](https://github.com/manubio/eu-decidi)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and put the **full text** of the error and traceback.

Comment: Try `from .app import app`.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance I'd say it's probably a circular import thing, as `models` which attempts to import `app` is required before `app` is defined. However, I do want to point out your app structure can be improved to make the application more understandable. Here is how I typically build my flask applications:

---

`run.py` (Application entry point)

`venv` (Virtual Environment)

`decidi` (Your application package, every .py file inside can be imported as a module of the package)

----- `__init__.py` (Python sees this filename and treats this whole folder as package)

----- `models.py`

----- `templates`

---------- `index.html`

----- `static` (Serves static files like css and images)

---

In `run.py`, it's quite simple. It imports app from the application package, in your case, `decidi`.

```
from decidi import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

In `decidi/__init__.py`, you put things you've got in your app.py. Note that the import of models must be done after `db` is initialized, otherwise it will cause circular import. Some editor may auto move the import, in which case you need to turn off the feature.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, redirect, flash
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__) #application instance
app.config['SECRET_KEY']= 'my_secret'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///myDB.db' #path to database and its name
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False #supress warning of changes on database
db = SQLAlchemy(app) #database instance

from decidi.models import Student # DO NOT PUT THIS AT THE TOP

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")
```

In `decidi/models.py`, you can import `db` directly from your application package, because it's inside `__init__.py` of the package:

```
from decidi import db

class Student(db.Model):
    #__tablename__ = 'student'
    student_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True) #primary Key column, automatically generated IDs
    student_name = db.Column(db.String(80), index = True, unique = False) #name of student
    student_surname = db.Column(db.String(100), index = True, unique = False) #surname of student
    student_phone = db.Column(db.Integer, index=True, unique = True) #student phone number
    student_email = db.Column(db.String(200), index=True, unique = True) #student email
 
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Aluno: {} {}, telefone: {}".format(self.student_name,self.student_surname,self.student_phone)
```

To run the app, cd into the directory where `run.py` is, activate the virtual environment, then simply `python3 run.py`.

I only kept the bulk of your code for simplicity's sake. But the gist is there. Feel free to ask me in comment if this caused confusion.

Comment: Thank you so much Agustín, just tried it out and it really works, besides been a lot more clean to work with!

Answer (score 0):

Create a main folder, move all the files and folders into that main folder except 'app.py' file. Save and then run.